# Must I use a Top Level Domain (TLD) for localhost websites?

Tags: domains, web-development, top-level-domains, localhost

I've always used **name.dev** for local development, but since [Google Chrome 63 update](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/669923/2/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json), out December 2017, domains with **.dev** are in the [preloaded HSTS list](https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-force-dev-domains-https-via-preloaded-hsts/) with a rule enforcing HTTPS, no workarounds.

[IETF states a few reserved TLDs for development:](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-2)

> 2. TLDs for Testing, & Documentation Examples
>
>    There is a need for top level domain (TLD) names that can be used
>    for    creating names which, without fear of conflicts with current or
>    future actual TLD names in the global DNS, can be used for private
>    testing of existing DNS related code, examples in documentation, DNS
>    related experimentation, invalid DNS names, or other similar uses.
>
>    For example, without guidance, a site might set up some local
>    additional unused top level domains for testing of its local DNS code
>    and configuration. Later, these TLDs might come into actual use on
>    the global Internet.  As a result, local attempts to reference the
>    real data in these zones could be thwarted by the local test
>    versions.  Or test or example code might be written that accesses a
>    TLD that is in use with the thought that the test code would only be
>    run in a restricted testbed net or the example never actually run.
>    Later, the test code could escape from the testbed or the example be
>    actually coded and run on the Internet. Depending on the nature of
>    the test or example, it might be best for it to be referencing a TLD
>    permanently reserved for such purposes.
>
>    To safely satisfy these needs, four domain names are reserved as
>    listed and described below.
>
>    ```
>                .test
>             .example
>             .invalid
>           .localhost
>    ```
>
>    ".test" is recommended for use in testing of current or new DNS
>    related code.
>
>    ".example" is recommended for use in documentation or as examples.
>
>    ".invalid" is intended for use in online construction of domain
>    names that are sure to be invalid and which it is obvious at a
>    glance are invalid.
>
>    The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in
>    host DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the
>    loop back IP address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use
>    would conflict with widely deployed code which assumes this use.

But I was wondering if I could use something shorter.
###Is it ok to use only `http://name` for local websites?

I mean, only the project name, without TLD. Similar to the
**localhost** "domain" itself.

Comment: Have a look at the ICANN SSAC report on dotless domains at: https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/sac-053-en.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Depending.

### Client Side:

Most OSs allow for the editing of the hosts or hosts.txt file to associate a network name or domain name with an IP address. This is a client side option. You would do this on your desktop computer so that it knows how to address the request packet. Here is more detailed information including example settings.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

You can configure another name for localhost, however, just adding a name will allow you to access the web server from a client on the same network. You would have to make this entry for all of the computers you expect to use in this manner. Assuming you are a developer, this is often the case where the client and web server are two different computers. Do not expect this to always work through a firewall over the Internet. It can, however, some firewalls may not allow it.

You can set your computer to use a search domain to append a domain name to the short name you provide. There is an excellent answer here for this. https://serverfault.com/questions/23397/resolving-host-names-to-their-domain-name-in-an-internal-bind-domain/23401#23401 This also requires a configuration change per computer that you intend to use in this manner.

### Server Side:

The problem begins with the web server. The assumption is that the web server can handle the name. Certainly, myawesomesite.test can easily be configured as a site. However, myawesomesite without the TLD may not be configurable. There are ways around this.

For example, with Apache, when a request packet comes in, Apache will try and match it with a configured site. If it cannot, it will serve the first site created. Often, this will be configured as a catch-all site intended to capture invalid requests and IP address only requests. This is not always done. However, the first site created can always be used for any site that cannot be properly configured by name or IP address only sites. Other web servers do this as well.

Certainly, any Apache server can be reconfigured to add a catch-all site where one does not exist. I cover some configuration examples here where a catch-all site exists. [Virtualhost config: routing and wildcard usage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/virtualhost-config-routing-and-wildcard-usage/83320#83320) Always take this task on with caution. You will likely have to experiment if you are not familiar with Apache configuration. And as always, Apache will have to be restarted before the configuration changes are taken in consideration.

As @StephenOstermiller points out in the comments, any existing site can simply have 'ServerAlias' set to an alternative name such as myawesomesite.test. He also points out that a shorter name can be used. I have not ever tried this. It costs relatively nothing to try it.

IIS should be able to use a NetBios name. If you are using a Windows network, you can look into this and it should do what you want.

For other web servers, I cannot give advice. Sorry. However, there is likely an answer if you research.

Comment: Right below `ServerName myapp.example.com` you can put `ServerAlias myapp`, `ServerAlias myapp.local` and `ServerAlias myapp.test` which will allow that virtual host either way that it is specified as long as you have a local way of mapping those via DNS.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Great input! I have never fooled around with site names less than a domain name with the exception of IIS 1000 years ago. IIS will, of course, use a Windows NETBIOS name. Cheers!!

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Added to answer. Please let me know how I can further improve this answer! Cheers!!

Comment: I'd include something about the DNS settings for "search domain".   If you have control over your local DHCP server, you can have it give your chosen fake TLD as the default for all DHCP connected clients.   That way you don't have to modify /etc/hosts on every computer.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller These are not things I use. I will look at DHCP and search domains later tonight. I have some of it already. I may need your help.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller *you can have it give your chosen fake TLD as the default for all DHCP connected clients* I am not familiar with how this works. I looked at the protocol, but I do not see what you mean?

Comment: .DEV is indeed now a true TLD, see https://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/dev.html so even without changes in Google product you will run into problems if you use fake names in this TLD, like in any other TLD.

Comment: “However, myawesomesite without the TLD may not be configurable” — this is just not true, not for any server I’ve used anyway. You can set up a virtual host for anything, dot or no dot.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat The operational word is *may*. ;-) You see I cheated... I only remember Apache these days and even then, I was an ISP so under no circumstances where there any servers without a domain name that cannot be reached by an internal DNS. I put the caveat in with the understanding that web servers are not intended to work any other way except for iis. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc DHCP allows client to get some configuration, like their IP address, the DNS server to query, and the search list, the list of suffix to automatically add to domain names without "enough" dots, like the `search` option in `/etc/resolv.conf`.  See this other question: https://serverfault.com/questions/37417/which-dhcp-client-os-support-dhcp-option-119-domain-suffix-search

Comment: @PatrickMevzek It has been a long time since I used DHCP. It was in a Windows environment. DHCP is not designed for the internet, but for IP based support for organizations. Back in the day, it would take a computer name and create a sub-domain and assign an IP address to it. It is possible to use these assignments on the internet with some mildly clever DNS. But not the norm in the ISP world. Not at least when I was an ISP. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc "... is not designed for the internet, but for IP based support for organizations" is a strange sentence. The internet is based on IP... (Client) computers do not need a name to go on the wil internet, they just need an IP. Anyway I was just pointing at a link if you want to learn about the intersection between DHCP and DNS features. Hope that helps.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek In order to configure a network card, the computer needs a name and often needs a FQDN depending. DHCP is just a centralized bit of software that makes the process transparent for organizations and users. You are right that all that is needed is an IP address to be addressed, but again, that is not the norm. Most computers do not have dedicated IP addresses nor do web sites. Hence the need for the web servers need to know what sites exist so that it can direct requests to the proper place. The ISP world does not use DHCP normally, though it could. It is a useful tool depending.

Comment: @closetnoc 1) no, the name is not required when you set-up an IP interface 2)  "Most computers do not have dedicated IP addresses nor do web sites." do not know what you mean. each computer has a dedicated IP address. May not be global (think NAT in IPv4) nor static, but it has one at each given moment. 3) "The ISP world does not use DHCP normally," certainly not true, ISPs of course use DHCP as static configurations would be a nightmare for hundreds, thousands or more customers... Anyway we are drifting off-topic here, so I will stop.

Comment: When I was an ISP and managed several thousands of servers for several telecoms for hosting, DHCP was not used. That was a while ago. As well, even the last install of Ubuntu I did about a year ago required a system name for the network interface. From there, if a domain name is used, the assumption made is that the FQDN was machine name as a sub-domain of the domain name. A FQDN is not required, however the machine name was. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The domain name in the URL `http://name/` does have a TLD, or rather: it consists only of a TLD ([`name`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.name)). It would be `http://name./` as FQDN, but the variant without the `.` typically works in browsers, too.

While it’s uncommon that TLD owners make the TLD itself resolvable, some do. For example, this [was the case with `http://to/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26188440/1591669), and it still is the case with `http://dk/`.

As of posting this answer, you can test it yourself: http://dk/ (currently redirects to a third-level domain name).

So is it "okay" to use them?

- No, if you want to prevent the possibility of getting surprised again in the future. The project name you choose could become a TLD, and this TLD could itself become resolvable. To be safe, stick with the reserved TLDs.
- Yes, if you can live with this risk. But if you use non-reserved TLDs, it might be a good idea to configure your system in such a way that DNS requests to these TLDs won’t go out.