# 503 service unavailable error for ALL files except PHP files when using Apache virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, linux

Apache 2.4/ PHP 7.0

Virtual hosts setup working correctly. There are no issues loading JPG files when pointing directly to the server using IP address.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com 
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/vhosts/example.com
  <Directory /var/www/html/vhosts/example.com>
    Require all granted
    <FilesMatch ".+\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
      Require all granted
    </FilesMatch>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

However the images do not load when pointing to the hostname (example.com).

`http://example.com/friendly.jpg` Response:

> Content-Type: text/html 503 Service Unavailable

As a workaround, I created a PHP symlink to the `friendly.jpg`

`mynewphpfile.php` -> `friendly.jpg`

`http://example.com/mynewphpfile.php` returns 200 successfully and displays friendly.jpg

Can you help resolve this issue?

**Additional Steps** 
*Modified /etc/hosts pointing example.com to IP*

**Executing from local www server:** 
`curl --head http://example.com/friendly.jpg` 
Returns: 200 OK successfully (correct image content-length in bytes shown)
Content-Type: image/jpeg

`curl -v http://example.com/friendly.jpg` 
Returns: 200 OK successfully (correct image content-length in bytes shown)
Content-Type: image/jpeg


**Executing from external machine:** 
`curl --head http://example.com/friendly.jpg`
 
Returns: 200 OK successfully (correct image content-length in bytes shown)
Content-Type: image/jpeg

`curl -v http://example.com/friendly.jpg`
 
Returns: 503 Service unavailable 
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: Have you tried removing the filesmatch directive? You will need to restart Apache to test. Also, it seems that your directory directive is not closed properly. Needs a slash. Outside of these two things, I do not see anything right off. Cheers!!

Comment: Yes I've tried both suggestions, but unfortunately it still doesn't work even without FilesMatch. This behavior seems very strange. In addition, the 503 errors do not appear in the logs and neither does the GET request for anything besides PHP files. Btw, the instance is running on AWS.

Comment: Okay. I am stumped! I will have to think on this. BTW- I use Apache. Not sure what differences there are between Apache and AWS if any.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant to note that the AWS instance is running httpd version of Apache.

Comment: Not sure this will help, however, I have some configuration examples here. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/virtualhost-config-routing-and-wildcard-usage/83320#83320

Comment: Are you using a load balancer, firewall, or a reverse proxy?   Since the requests are not appearing in the log file I suspect something is filtering them before they get to your server. Elastic load balancers use 503. Use `curl --head http://example.com/friendly.jpg` both from the server itself and from an external machine.   See if there are differences.  Check for an `X-Powered-By` header.  Set the hostname and IP address in `/etc/hosts` and try again making sure DNS is pointing directly to the server and not through some intermediary.  Edit your question and add the findings from those.

Comment: This also happens when a framework is not configured properly. Does the site live on a php framework, like laravel, yii, code igniter etc.? They  have a router where you configure how to handle urls for dynamic content and for static content. Static content directory and path needs to be configured in its config file.

Comment: Thanks guys. Stephen, I think there may be some intermediary. When executing a PHP file with $_REQUEST to see the headers, I noticed NetScaler shown along with Apache/PHP. However, I never set this up nor do I see it installed on my machine.