# How to remove the wildcard subdomain on Apache to prevent Google from indexing Subdomains that do not exist

Tags: seo, apache, subdomain, virtualhost

I am experiencing the issue explained at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065450/subdomains-that-dont-exist-are-indexed-by-google-zombie-subdomain-removal-via. Notice how the the search engine Google returns a result linking to my site (see the image below):

[image]

I never configured `ww.w` as a subdomain in my Apache configuration. I have no idea where Google took that from. I did configure `https://www.jaimemontoya.com` to simply redirect to `https://jaimemontoya.com`, which means simply removing the `www`. I did that by creating a `CNAME` Record to specify that `www.jaimemontoya.com` is an alias of `jaimemontoya.com`. But I never configured anything for `ww.w` as a `CNAME` Records, nor in the Apache configurations. I wonder where Google took that configuration from.

What I understand from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065450/subdomains-that-dont-exist-are-indexed-by-google-zombie-subdomain-removal-via, in the answer by @MrWhite, was that the solution is: "Remove the wildcard subdomain and it will resolve your issue." How are wildcard subdomains removed? Is that done from the Apache configuration, or by creating DNS Records maybe for `*` to apply to all subdomains? I am guessing I might need to write something in a `<VirtualHost *:443>` block in the Apache configuration, to remove wildcards for subdomains. Thank you.

UPDATE 1: I am running the website on a DigitalOcean Virtual Private Server. This is not a shared hosting service and I have created the Apache configurations myself from scratch. So I am not using any of the pre-built standard configurations that shared hosting services typically provide.

UPDATE 2: Find updates to this question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77558953/how-to-remove-the-wildcard-subdomain-on-apache-to-prevent-google-from-indexing-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildcard subdomains are specified in DNS.  To remove the wildcard subdomain you need to remove the `*` record from your DNS records.

You could also configure Apache to respond with 404 errors for unrecognized host names.  To do this, create two `VirtualHost` directives.  Whichever one comes first is the default one that is used for unknown host names. [Virtualhost config: routing and wildcard usage](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/83316/virtualhost-config-routing-and-wildcard-usage) has example configuration for this.

Comment: I have an A Record with a `*`, as seen in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEk6d.png. I guess I need to remove that and then configure Apache Virtual Hosts for each of the subdomains that are being problematic by Google indexing them (`w`, `ww.w`, etc.) I do not need subdomains and I would like to have `https://w.example.com/post-entry/` redirecting to `https://example.com/post-entry/`, and  `https://ww.w.example.com/post-entry/` redirecting to `https://example.com/post-entry/`. I have no idea where Google found those subdomains `w` and `ww.w` that I never configured on Apache.

Comment: Once you remove the `*`, those problematic subdomains will no longer resolve, so putting specific config in Apache for them would be pointless.

Comment: I tried what you said and you are right. The only problem is that Google already indexed https://ww.w.jaimemontoya.com/blog/2023/10/17/23/21/ and when people click on it, the site no longer resolves, which means losing that traffic. The ideal case scenario would be for that visit to be redirected to https://jaimemontoya.com/blog/2023/10/17/23/21/. But in that case I guess I need to create an Apache Virtual Host for `ww.w`, or maybe a ServerAlias so that the `ww.w` is removed, similar to how when people visit `www.example.com/my-page/` they are redirected to `example.com/my-page/`.

Comment: If I remove the `* A Record`, this is what my domain registrar tool does: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDkqA.png.

Comment: What is Turbify Hostname?

Comment: Can you change your DNS hosting to be handled by DigitalOcean?  You'd need to recreate your DNS records in DigitalOcean's interface and then update the NS records at your registrar to point to them.

Comment: Ok @StephenOstermiller. Answering to your question, on June 10, 2022, Verizon's Small Business Essentials (formerly Yahoo Small Business) was acquired by Infinite Computer Solutions. It is being rebranded as Turbify. Yahoo / Verizon Small Business is now Turbify. I am going to change my domain registrar from Turbify to Namecheap. After that, I will change my NS Records for DigitalOcean to handle my DNS configurations, and I will proceed to do what you mentioned about the DNS settings that I need to fix my issue.

Comment: To answer your question @StephenOstermiller, this is what "Turbify Hostname" refers to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atdfZ.png.

Comment: Must be some sort of domain parking service.  I've never seen a registrar try to put in a wildcard like that for it.  :(

Comment: Your solution worked! Thank you. I explained my step-by-step solution at https://jaimemontoya.com/blog/2023/11/29/02/48/, which required to change name domain name registrar from Turbify to Namecheap. Turbify for some reason did not allow to remove `*` from both `A` and `CNAME` Records. They required `*` to exist in one or the other, never allowing it to be removed from both `A` and `CNAME` Records. After switching companies from Turbify to Namecheap, I did what you suggested, which was to change my DNS hosting to be handled by DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. I had for example these problematic instances:

[image]

[image]

Now when clicking those links, the result is this:

Result for the first link in the SERPS:

[image]

Result for the blog:

[image]

The root cause of the problem was that Turbify, my previous domain name registrar, was forcing the existance of the `*` A Record, and if deleted, it would create a `*` CNAME Record. It was impossible with Turbify to remove the `*` Record in the form of either `CNAME` or `A` Record. I explained my step-by-step solution at `https://jaimemontoya.com/blog/2023/11/29/02/48/`.